# How is it better to keep one .clang-format over git repositories?

Tags: git, clang-format

I just want to have the same `.clang-format` in several repositories and edit it in one place.
My projects are cross-platform mostly - so solution should work well on Windows/Linux/Macos. I see one solution:

1. place `.clang-format` in separate repo (f.e. `common`)
2. `git submodule` `tools/clang` to that repo
3. `ln -s tools/clang/.clang-format .clang-format`
4. `git add .clang-format`

Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: On Unix the approach seems to be the most sensible. But how do you plan to handle `ln -s` on w64?

Comment: @phd I did not try, but it seems it already supported: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links

Comment: However you'll need separate scripts to call either `ln -s` or `mklink`, so its awesome if you're using cmake, you can call `git submodule update --init` with `execute_process`, then use `configure_file` to copy from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/clang/.clang-format` to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`

Comment: Yes, I'm using cmake, interesting approach, thank you @JonnySoe .  
At the moment I'm calling `git submodule update ...` manually. But I should not call `ln -s` or `mklink` manually... Once I've added symbolic link to git repo git creating it for me. The only issue could happen if I forgot to update submodules. In that case link is pointing to nothing...